# empty array in instance variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

im learning about laravel and im following some videos from laracasts, but im having a issue in displaying the data from the controller, i made all right, but still appears me empty array, the instance Card isnt working, here is my code:

Model:
Card.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Card extends Model
{
    //
}
```

route:

```
Route::get('cards/{card}', 'CardsController@show');
```

CardsController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Card;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;



class CardsController extends Controller
{

    public function show(Card $card)
    {
        return $card;
        //$card = Card::find($card);
        //return view('cards.show', compact('card'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting is called "Route Model Binding" and it seems to me that you are using Laravel 5.1 or lower (where route model binding is not implicit).
If you are using Laravel 5.2 or higher that code should just work. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding

But, if you are in Laravel 5.1 you need to do an additional step: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-model-binding

In the provider class `RouteServiceProvider`, in the `boot` method, you need to bind which route name `{card}` should bind to which Model, in this case `Card`.
So, you do something like this:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);
    $router->model('card', \App\Card::class);
}
```

If you add that, the router will know that when it finds `{card}` it should get that number and do the `Card::findOrFail` with the ID automatically and if the model is found it will be passed down to your controller.

Comment: Thanks Nestor , just one more question, how can Laravel relate the Model Card with the table cards in the Database? How does it no?

Comment: When you inherited from the class Model (which you do in your own models) it by default uses the name of the class, convert that name to plural and uses that as the table name when doing a query. But, in fact, you can override that by setting the protected property in the class `$table`, like this: `protected $table = 'other_name_for_cards_table';` . You can read more about this in https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to add the fillable protected property to your Eloquent model! Now, on to the good part.

In your routes file you have

```
Route::get('cards/{card}', 'CardsController@show');
```

This code, in a nutshell, will pass the card **ID** to your show function in your CardsController class. Eg. for this route: `https://example.com/cards/5`, it will in essence call the function show like this: `show(5)`. In your code, you have that the show parameter is typehinted to be a Card. **This is wrong**. This is going to be an integer.

Thus, what you really need to do is check whether this ID exists and then pass the relevant information to your view. Something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Card;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;



class CardsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Show the relevant card information
     * 
     * @param $card This is the card ID (its an integer)
     */
    public function show($card)
    {
        $card = Card::findOrFail($card);
        return view('cards.show')->with(compact('card'));
    }
}
```

Comment: What he is doing is not wrong, is actually a feature of Laravel (Route Model Binding), you can read about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding